# htaccess problem

Tags: .htaccess

I given htaccess like this

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /xxx/folder/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .  /xxx/folder/index.php [L]

RewriteRule  ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

but giving the url like this
http://domain.com/faq

I get the page variable as index.php. I want to get  faq in $_GET['page'].How can i get this?

Comment: remove this line RewriteRule .  /xxx/folder/index.php [L]

Comment: Tried with removing that line.But the page deosn't goes in index.php

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
RewriteBase /xxx/folder/
```

Modify

```
RewriteRule  ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

to

```
RewriteRule  ^(.*)$ xxx/folder/index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Tried with that.then the  page variable shown as faq.html.But I need as faq.

Comment: do u mean http://domain.com/faq doesn't work but http://domain.com/faq.html does ?

Comment: the page is redirecting to index.php.In index page i print the $_GET array.In it it shown as faq.html